# Why does IPAddress.MapToIPv4() throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException?

Tags: .net, ipv6, ipv4, base-class-library, bug-reporting

This code throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException on the last line

```
var initAddress = IPAddress.Parse("1.65.128.190");
var ipv6Address = initAddress.MapToIPv6();
Assert.IsTrue(ipv6Address.IsIPv4MappedToIPv6);
var ipv4Address = ipv6Address.MapToIPv4();
```

Can anyone explain why MapToIPv6() and MapToIPv4() are not round trip compatible?

edit: The exception originates from the IPAddress constructor, called by MapToIPv4().

Also, when the first line is

```
var initAddress = IPAddress.Parse("1.65.128.90");
```

no exceptions are thrown anymore

edit2: as @Luaan reproduced this, I added the tag [bug-reporting]. Also added [bcl]. Let's see if any MS personnel tracks those tags :)

edit3: reported at Connect https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/871964

Comment: Interesting. There's a lot of IPv4 addresses for which this works just fine. In fact, based on some ad-hoc testing, it seems that the last bit is to blame - perhaps there's an error somewhere in the code that so liberally uses `long`, `ulong` and `int` casts with positive and negative numbers. Why do you want IPv6 mapped IPv4 addresses anyway, though? Are you working with linux servers? I thought Windows doesn't really handle those (since IPv4 and IPv6 are separate drivers on the networking stack - you need two separate sockets to handle both IPv4 and IPv6).

Comment: Well, I don't really need it, but I considered it a small win when comparing addresses. I guess I'm lucky the tests of my code actually had an address like this, to steer me away from my premature (unprofiled) optimization...

Comment: @PatrickHuizinga Ah, I've been posting the bug report as well. Anyway, I upped yours :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, I've actually verified this, so let me post this as an answer.

The `IPAddress` class has an error when mapping the address back to IPv4.

According to the .NET reference code, it does this:

```
long address = 
  (((m_Numbers[6] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) | ((m_Numbers[6] & 0x000000FF) << 8)) |
  ((((m_Numbers[7] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) | ((m_Numbers[7] & 0x000000FF) << 8)) << 16);
```

The problem should be quite obvious to anyone doing bitwise operations in .NET - the numbers are all `int`s. So shifting the second `ushort` (`m_Numbers[7]`) will give a negative value, because the most significant bit is `1`. This means that all IPv4 addresses that end with a byte higher than `127` will cause an error when mapping back from IPv6.

The simple fix would be this:

```
long address = 
 (((m_Numbers[6] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) | ((m_Numbers[6] & 0x000000FF) << 8)) 
 |
 (
  (uint)(((m_Numbers[7] & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) | ((m_Numbers[7] & 0x000000FF) << 8))
  << 16
 );
```

Just by casting the `int` to an `uint` before doing the bitshift does the trick.

Bitwise operations can be quite tricky when you factor in signed types. I guess the code was copied from a C++ library or something, where this issue wouldn't manifest.

Comment: Are you saying this is essentially a bug in the .NET source? - Should Microsoft be notified of this?

Comment: @series0ne Yup, it's now been reported - https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/871964/ipaddress-maptoipv4-throws-argumentoutofrangeexception

Comment: Just for everyone's reference, I hit this on a fully patched server running .NET Framework 4.5.2, so I suppose the fix won't be until 4.6