# Visual Studio 2010 MapToIPv4

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Do you have any idea to change the code and avoid to use MapToIPv4 because my computer is Visual studio 2010?

```
    hostIP = ipHostInfo.AddressList(CType(logNconfig.Addresslist.ToString(), Integer))
    TxtIP.Text = hostIP.MapToIPv4.ToString()

    hostIP = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(TxtIP.Text)

    server = Nothing
    server = New TcpListener(hostIP, TxtPort.Text)

    server.Start()
```

Do you have any idea to solve this? :( i want run it as visual studio 2010..

Comment: You *could* go and look at the [Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/IPAddress.cs,cae19ee54c742f78). However, there's a problem - the code is actually buggy. So you would actually also want to examine [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23608829/why-does-ipaddress-maptoipv4-throw-argumentoutofrangeexception)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the IPaddress by using

`Dim hostname As String = Dns.GetHostName()
Dim ipaddress As String = CType(Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname).AddressList.GetValue(0), IPAddress).ToString`

[View Sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212892/how-to-get-local-ip-address-using-vb)